# DataTrigger in ControlTemplate breaks MultiBinding

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, controltemplate

I have following ControlTemplate which works fine

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TotalCostsStatisticTemplate">
    <StackPanel x:Name="ContentHolderPanel" Visibility="Collapsed"
                Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ValueTextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   Style="{DynamicResource PhasingValueTextStyle}">
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{ttConverters:CustomDisplayFormatConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="FormatSettings" />
                    <Binding Path="AvailableStatistics.CostsFormat"/>
                    <Binding Path="TotalCosts" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowTotalCosts}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="ContentHolderPanel" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

But if I add another DataTrigger then the MultiBinding on TextBlock.Text doesn't work when control using this template is loaded for first time i.e. the converter CustomDisplayFormatConverter fires only once with all values as UnsetValue and doesn't fire again (it works fine on reloading the window again).

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TotalCostsStatisticTemplate">
    <StackPanel x:Name="ContentHolderPanel" Visibility="Collapsed"
                Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ValueTextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   Style="{DynamicResource PhasingValueTextStyle}">
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{ttConverters:CustomDisplayFormatConverter1}">
                    <Binding Path="FormatSettings" />
                    <Binding Path="AvailableStatistics.CostsFormat"/>
                    <Binding Path="TotalCosts" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowTotalCosts}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="ContentHolderPanel" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>

     <!--Trigger causing problem (breaking TextBlock.Text multi binding on first load) -->
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCostsComplete}" Value="False">

            <Setter TargetName="ValueTextBlock" Property="Foreground" 
                    Value="{DynamicResource ManagerErrorBrush}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

If I place this DataTrigger inside TextBlock.Style it works fine!

Any idea what's wrong?

**Update:**

Here's how its getting used

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="PhasingStatisticValuesTemplate">
    <StackPanel x:Name="ContentHolderPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding IsValid, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}">

        <!-- Other control elements based on various templates -->

        <Control Margin="20,10" Template="{DynamicResource TotalCostsStatisticTemplate}"/>

    </StackPanel>

</ControlTemplate>
```

This PhasingStatisticValuesTemplate is used in another ControlTemplate, which is then used inside a DataTemplate, so there is a long hierarchy of ControlTemplates -

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="PhasingStatisticsTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer Style="{DynamicResource CompactHorizontalScrollViewerStyle}" Name="ScrollContainer">
            <Grid Name="ScrollViewerGrid" Background="Transparent">
                <ContentControl Template="{DynamicResource PhasingStatisticValuesTemplate}" Name="ScrollViewerContent" />
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Another useful info. might be that existing style on that TextBlock also updated Foreground, not sure how that can cause this behavior -

```
<Style x:Key="PhasingValueTextStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsComplete}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ManagerErrorBrush}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue using the XAML markup you provided. Maybe it's important how the `ControlTemplate` is applied. Can you extend your example?

Comment: @dymanoid thanks for looking into this, I have added some more details but its hard to provide the full usage as its used in very complex and lengthy window.

Comment: Thanks for more details. Unfortunately there are still no issues with that thing, the binding works on my system. Have you tried to set a break point in your converter and to compare the stack traces for the "good" and the "bad" cases?

Comment: @dymanoid Yes, I did that and the converter fires only once; for the first time when window is loaded it gets fired with DependencyProperty.UnsetValue for all bindings and is never fired again. Whereas it works fine without DataTrigger and is fired multiple times on property changes.